# How to add a 2D subarray in an existing 2D array using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having problem to add a subarray to an existing 2D array.
I am actually new to numpy and python and coming from MATLAB this was something trivial to do.
Note that usually a is a big matrix in my problems.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(arange(16)).reshape(4,4) # The initial array
b = np.array(arange(4)).reshape(2,2) # The subarray to add to the initial array
ind = [0,3] # The rows and columns to add the 2x2 subarray 

a[ind][:,ind] += b #Doesn't work although does not give an error
```

I saw looking around that the following can work

```
a[:4:3,:4:3] += b
```

but how can I define ind beforehand?
In addition how to define ind if it consists of more than two numbers that cannot be expressed with a stride? for example ind = [1, 15, 34, 67]

Comment: Just to explain why `a[ind][:,ind] += b` doesn't work, it's because `a[ind]` (where `ind` is a sequence of coordinates) makes a copy.  Therefore, it does work, but the `+=` is applied to the copy, which is not saved.  `a` winds up being unchanged.  Basically, it's because you have use "fancy" indexing twice. @DSM's answer combines it into one "fancy" indexing expression, so `+=` works as expected.  Another way to write it is `a[ind[:,None], ind[None,:]] += b`, but that requires `ind` to be a numpy array instead of a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to handle the general case would be to use [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```
>>> a = np.zeros((4,4))
>>> b = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)+1
>>> ind = [0,3]
>>> np.ix_(ind, ind)
(array([[0],
       [3]]), array([[0, 3]]))
>>> a[np.ix_(ind, ind)] += b
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  0.,  0.,  4.]])
```